# Spring Boot Gradle bootRun task default classpath and current working directory

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I am going to test external config for application. What is default classpath and default working directory for Spring Boot Gradle bootRun task?

I didn't get in from:

- http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-running-your-application.html
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html

**UPDATE** test with `System.getProperty("user.dir")` show that current directory is where Gradle is started.

Answer (score 2):

Working directory is actually the module with Spring Boot project, which does not necessarily have to be the `rootProject`.

Classpath for `bootRun` is:

- working directory (or Gradle project directory with Spring Boot)
- main classes
- runtime classpath

At least this is what seems to be the default when I debug the build (now easily possible with IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2).